# Make sense to use code formatter template arbitrary in team?

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style, formatting

I am working on a Java project, about ten developers in team. And we all use Eclipse as IDE.

To make source code in more consistent style in team, I am wondering if it makes sense to use code formatter template arbitrary? I mean only thing prior to checking in code is to use code formatter in Eclipse.

In general, I know the team will benefit from consistent code style. The problem is - should it works as a force rule? maybe it's too rigid.

Example 1: The template forces the maximum line width as 80. but it's ugly if some lines are broken into many lines. sure I know the 80 is configurable.

Example 2: Formatted code by Eclipse:

```
int green = 1;
int red = 1;
int orange = 1;
```

My prefer code:

```
int green  = 1;
int red    = 1;
int orange = 1;
```

So my opinion is to use code template, but not rigid, violation to the template is allowable and necessary. What is your opinion about it?

Comment: Since this is an open ended question you are better off asking it here - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather create a document that assembles the rules, and get everyone to read it.
The rules are there to be broken, and you not always want your code formatter to automatically do the work for you (in my case this often happens with multiline if statements).

And because you will not always apply to the coding standard, everytime someone uses an automatic formatter, he/she will cause havoc in your git/svn/cvs, changing lines, that actually did not change.

So my advice - don't use automatic formatting, and convince/learn/force people to write readable code. And make code reviews too!

Answer (score 2):

What we use is **[checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)**, configured both in [Eclipse](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) (to help developers while coding) and as a [Maven plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/) to make automatic validations and reports. It checks [Sun/Oracle Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) (they are the de facto standard) and other good practices. Everyone know the rules and can apply some small automatic formatting tips that match the conventions (i.e. spacing, ...). We also make code reviews.

In most cases, I would try to avoid taking personal opinions into account because that only leads to flame wars in the development teams. For example, in your example 2, Eclipse applies the "standard" formatitng, so I would not try to use another format just because someone personally thinks that it could be easier to understand.

In my opinion this has several advantages:

- From a "collective code ownership" point of view, all the code seems to be written by the very same person.
- It is easier to move developers between different projects.
- The code is easier to read an maintain.
- It does not matter if anyone prefer other IDE.

For new projects, once you have automatic checkstyle validations with Maven, I think it is a good idea to make strict validations. That is, treat code style errors as compilation errors (not just warnings), the build is broken if the code style is not valid. It requires a little bit of discipline at the beginning, but it leads to a higher code quality at the end.

Answer (score 0):

We check the formatter configuration into version control, and have the formatter configured as save action.

This requires everyone to use eclipse, but you already do that.

It has the following advantages:

- formatting is consistent
- nobody spends time formatting the code
- nobody argues about formatting in a code review

It has the disadvantage that on occasion the formatter will do something weird. This can be adressed as follows:

- rewrite the statement in question (for instance, extract local variables to shorten lines and avoid line wrapping)
- give hints to the formatter (for instance, you can force line breaks to remain by following them with `//`
- disable the formatter for a section of code using an on/off tag